# How to dynamically generate and store state of a custom stateful widget in the parent class?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently stuck with dynamic generation of widget and its state maintenance.

This is my code.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              DescriptionTextField(),
              DividerAddDescription(onPressed: () => print('Add another description'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class DescriptionTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white38),
      child: TextField(
        minLines: 1,
        maxLines: null,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter description',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class DividerAddDescription extends StatelessWidget {
  DividerAddDescription({@required this.onPressed});

  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Divider(
            thickness: 1,
          ),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Color(0xFF232F34),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is how the screen looks like.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve:

- when clicking on the plus button, another `DescriptionTextField` will be added to the `Column` widget.
- as a new `DescriptionTextField` is added, if the previous `DescriptionTextField` has description text in it, the text should be preserved.

What I don't know how to do:

- where should the description text be stored? Is it in `DescriptionTextField`'s state? i.e. do I need to make it a Stateful widget instead?
- when I have multiple `DescriptionTextField`, how am I supposed to store the state? e.g. the description text

Answer (score 1):

You should create a **List** variable in your **State**, add the new elements there and call the **setState** method when adding.

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
   //Create a field which hold the elements
  List<DescriptionTextField> myDescriptions = List<DescriptionTextField>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ...myDescriptions, //Add the elements to the Column using the spread operator
              DividerAddDescription(onPressed: () => setState(() => myDescriptions.add(DescriptionTextField(key: UniqueKey()))) //Adding new widget
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I recommend you to use a key value in your DescriptionTextField widgets, because you will be adding widget dynamically and Flutter could struggle to match the respectively their states.

There are of course many improvements, but from my perspective and what I understand from your description, this may help you.

Comment: how can I store the state of `DescriptionTextField` when i have a few of it? e.g. user keeps adding new `DescriptionTextField`.

Comment: Did you try adding the key value to DescriptionTextField widget, just like the example I sent? **DescriptionTextField(key: UniqueKey())** and conver the DescriptionTextField  to a StateFulWidget is it's required to change, save the TexField  value of the in variable in the DescriptionTextField's state throught onChanged function or using a TextEditingController (in the state or course).